# How to create MBR partition /dev/ nodes FreeBSD for mounting

Tags: mount, freebsd, mbr

I currently have FreeBSD version FreeBSD 10.0-RELEASE. Installed using a ZFS root. I'm attempting to mount a MBR partitioned drive but I can't get the partition nodes, `/dev/ada4p1`, etc. The partitions are formatted to EXT2.

Is there a kernel module or command I need to run to gain access to partitions on ada4?

```
[root@core /mnt]# ls -l /dev/ada*
crw-r-----  1 root  operator  0x76 May  2 10:29 /dev/ada0
crw-r-----  1 root  operator  0x79 May  2 10:29 /dev/ada0p1
crw-r-----  1 root  operator  0x7b May  2 10:29 /dev/ada0p2
crw-r-----  1 root  operator  0x7d May  2 10:29 /dev/ada0p3
crw-r-----  1 root  operator  0x8b May  2 10:29 /dev/ada0p4
crw-r-----  1 root  operator  0x9f May  2 10:29 /dev/ada0p4.eli
crw-r-----  1 root  operator  0x8d May  2 10:29 /dev/ada1
crw-r-----  1 root  operator  0x98 May  2 10:30 /dev/ada1.eli
crw-r-----  1 root  operator  0x8f May  2 10:29 /dev/ada2
crw-r-----  1 root  operator  0xa1 May  2 10:30 /dev/ada2.eli
crw-r-----  1 root  operator  0x91 May  2 10:29 /dev/ada3
crw-r-----  1 root  operator  0xa2 May  2 10:30 /dev/ada3.eli
crw-r-----  1 root  operator  0x93 May  2 10:29 /dev/ada4


[root@core /mnt]# fdisk /dev/ada4
******* Working on device /dev/ada4 *******
parameters extracted from in-core disklabel are:
cylinders=7752021 heads=16 sectors/track=63 (1008 blks/cyl)

Figures below won't work with BIOS for partitions not in cyl 1
parameters to be used for BIOS calculations are:
cylinders=7752021 heads=16 sectors/track=63 (1008 blks/cyl)

Media sector size is 512
Warning: BIOS sector numbering starts with sector 1
Information from DOS bootblock is:
The data for partition 1 is:
sysid 131 (0x83),(Linux native)
    start 1, size 3906250000 (1907348 Meg), flag 0
        beg: cyl 0/ head 0/ sector 2;
        end: cyl 1023/ head 254/ sector 63
The data for partition 2 is:
sysid 131 (0x83),(Linux native)
    start 3906250752, size 3907784704 (1908098 Meg), flag 0
        beg: cyl 1023/ head 254/ sector 63;
        end: cyl 1023/ head 254/ sector 63
The data for partition 3 is:
<UNUSED>
The data for partition 4 is:
<UNUSED>
```

Comment: `fdisk` is kind of legacy. Can you show us the result of `gpart ada4` please?

Comment: Here is the gpart for ada4
`
root@core:~ # gpart list /dev/ada4
gpart: No such geom: /dev/ada4.
root@core:~ #
`

The disk was created on a linux machine using parted. This handled the creation of both the partition table and the two partitions.

Comment: I meant `gpart show ada4` ... but it seems your ada4 disk is not mapped properly by the *geom* driver.

Comment: Normally, your partitions would show up as `/dev/ada4s1` and `/dev/ada4s2` (p# is for GPT partitions, s# is MBR slices).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your Linux formatted `/dev/ada4` *MBR* disk is not recognized properly by **FreeBSD** *geom* driver. So it can be seen through the legacy `fdisk` utility, but not through `gpart show ada4`.

It might be due to the fact that this `ada4` device is obviously using some non-standard MBR extension to handle 2TB+ disks (2 partitions that are almost 2 TB each).

From [*MBR* wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record):

> *MBR* partition entries and the *MBR* boot code used in commercial operating systems, however, **are limited to 32 bits**. Therefore, the maximum disk size supported on disks using 512-byte sectors (whether real or emulated) by the *MBR* partitioning scheme (without using non-standard methods) is **limited to 2 TB**. Consequently, a different partitioning scheme must be used for larger disks, as they have become widely available since 2010. The *MBR* partitioning scheme is therefore in the process of being superseded by the GUID Partition Table (*GPT*). The official approach does little more than ensuring data integrity by employing a protective MBR. Specifically, it does not provide backward compatibility with operating systems that do not support the GPT scheme as well. In the meanwhile, **multiple forms of hybrid MBRs have been designed and implemented by third-parties** in order to maintain partitions located in the first physical 2 TB of a disk in both partitioning schemes "in parallel" and/or to allow older operating systems to boot off *GPT* partitions as well. The present, **non-standard nature, of these solutions can cause various compatibility problems** in certain scenarios though.

**FreeBSD** preference is now about *GPT* partitioning scheme and both *MBR* and the `fdisk` utility are to consider legacy regarding non-removable media.

Comment: Do you know of any alternative way to get the data off the drive and onto freeBSD without purchasing another hdd ?

Answer (score 1):

Try running:

`kldload geom_part_mbr.ko`

then `gpart show /dev/ada4`

Your two 2TB partitions should be listed as `/dev/ada4s1` and `/dev/ada4s2`

However, using MBR on disks over 2TB is non-standard, so it might not work.